# Что значит "Low density device" в параметрах микроконтроллера STM?

Tags: микроконтроллеры, stm32

Микроконтроллеры STM32 / STM8 есть нескольких типов:

- low density devices
- medium density devices
- high density devices

С переводом конечно же проблем нет, но вот о какой плотности конкретно идет речь мне не совсем понятно. Это плотность периферии (чем выше, тем больше разной) или же это плотность памяти в устройстве, а может речь о чем-то другом?
Кто может помочь?

Comment: Насколько знаю, по объему flash памяти они делят.

Comment: @Илья, желательно хотя бы давать ссылку на [полученный правильный ответ](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/248175/what-does-low-density-device-mean-about-stm8-stm32). А еще лучше перевод, раз уж существует ru.stackoverflow и вопрос задан здесь.

Comment: @imbearr, думал об этом, но времени не было перенести ответ сюда. Сейчас сделаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За [ответ на вопрос](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/248175/what-does-low-density-device-mean-about-stm8-stm32) огромное спасибо @duskwuff.
Перевожу:

> Это всего лишь произвольное наименование, для того, чтобы различать
>   разные линейки МК из одной серии. Все МК в линейке будут иметь
>   одинаковый набор периферии и характеристики. Различия будут лишь в
>   RAM, Flash и способе упаковки (возможно имеется ввиду корпусировка). В
>   некоторых сериях также присутствуют типы "value line" и "connectivity
>   line". Их тоже стоит рассматривать как отдельные линейки МК.

Comment: Я невнимательно прочел вчера этот ответ. Это не совсем верно **одинаковый набор периферии и характеристики** МК линейки _high density_ будут иметь наиболее широкий набор периферии, и он будет уменьшаться для _medium_ и _low_ линеек, также будут различия и в характеристиках.

Comment: Одинаковый набор периферии и характеристики, в одной серии и в одной линейке - действительно верно. Я невнимателен.

Answer (score 0):

Вот выдержка из Application Note на STM32F10*. Может будет полезно.
Здесь как раз видны отличия для каждой линейки контроллеров.

> **Glossary**
>
> - Low-density value line devices are STM32F100xx microcontrollers where the Flash memory density ranges between 16 and 32 Kbytes.
> - Low-density devices are STM32F101xx, STM32F102xx and STM32F103xx microcontrollers where the Flash memory density ranges between 16 and
>   32 Kbytes.
> - Medium-density value line devices are STM32F100xx microcontrollers    where the Flash memory density ranges between 64 and 128 Kbytes.
> - Medium-density devices are STM32F100xx, STM32F101xx, STM32F102xx and     STM32F103xx microcontrollers where the Flash memory density
>   ranges       between 64 and 128 Kbytes.
> - High-density value line devices are    STM32F100xx microcontrollers    where the Flash memory density ranges    between 256 and 512 Kbytes.
> - High-density devices are STM32F101xx and STM32F103xx microcontrollerswhere the Flash memory density ranges between 256 and
>   512 Kbytes.
> - XL-density devices are    STM32F101xx and STM32F103xx microcontrollers where the Flash memory density ranges between 768
>   Kbytes and 1 Mbyte.
> - Connectivity line devices are STM32F105xx and STM32F107xx    microcontrollers.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! а что, простого текста у вас нет? [картинки - это сплошное неудобство](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help